# Add slide to section

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to add a slide, created with the below code, to a specific section called "Index".

Currently it is going two slides below the last one but because the number of slides will be chaining I can't reference using -2 function so I have to resort to section referencing.

```
Public Function GetLayout( _
    LayoutName As String, _
    Optional ParentPresentation As Presentation = Nothing) As CustomLayout

    If ParentPresentation Is Nothing Then
        Set ParentPresentation = ActivePresentation
    End If

    Dim oLayout As CustomLayout
    For Each oLayout In ParentPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
        If oLayout.Name = LayoutName Then
            Set GetLayout = oLayout
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function

Sub AddCustomSlide()
    Dim oSlides As Slides, oSlide As Slide
    Set oSlides = ActivePresentation.Slides
    Set oSlide = oSlides.AddSlide(oSlides.Count - 2, GetLayout("Processwindow"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the `.MoveToSectionStart` method of the `Slide` object.

In your `AddCustomSlide` routine, add one line:

```
Sub AddCustomSlide()
    Dim oSlides As Slides, oSlide As Slide
    Set oSlides = ActivePresentation.Slides
    Set oSlide = oSlides.AddSlide(oSlides.Count - 2, GetLayout("Title Only"))
    oSlide.MoveToSectionStart GetSectionNumber("Index")
End Sub
```

Since you need the section number of the "Index" section, I've written a quick function to return that number:

```
Private Function GetSectionNumber( _
        ByVal sectionName As String, _
        Optional ParentPresentation As Presentation = Nothing) As Long

    If ParentPresentation Is Nothing Then
        Set ParentPresentation = ActivePresentation
    End If

    GetSectionNumber = -1
    With ParentPresentation.SectionProperties
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To .Count
            If .Name(i) = sectionName Then
                GetSectionNumber = i
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking for ! Do you know the command to replace .MoveToSectionStart to move it to the end ? I've tryed .MoveToSectionEnd and it does not work.